# Okhttp - java, issue with getting url from response

Tags: java, request, okhttp

I am trying to log in to a website called Stockx (http://stockx.com/login). To send appropriate requests I need state and clientID from the response (**fetchstate**) headers or url. ClienID is okay but state shall look like this:

*hKFo2SBTb0hLMENwUHFIWXlLcTVRaTU2RUduMkR6T2NnMXFhcqFupWxvZ2luo3RpZNkgdnY2emVyNjdzU1o0ekI4YV9RQll2Q3lvVWNld3B5TV-jY2lk2SBPVnhydDRWSnFUeDdMSVVLZDY2MVcwRHVWTXBjRkJ5RA*

but my code always gives: *%7B%7D*

Here is my code

```
public class Stockx_login {
    String email;
    String password;
    OkHttpClient client;
    CookieJar cookieJar;

    public Stockx_login(String email, String password) throws IOException {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;

        this.cookieJar = new CookieJar() {
            private final HashMap<String, List<Cookie>> cookieStore = new HashMap<>();

            @Override
            public void saveFromResponse(HttpUrl url, @NotNull List<Cookie> cookies) {
                cookieStore.put(url.host(), cookies);
            }

            @Override
            public List<Cookie> loadForRequest(HttpUrl url) {
                List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.get(url.host());
                return cookies != null ? cookies : new ArrayList<>();
            }
        };

        this.client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cookieJar(cookieJar)
                .followRedirects(true)
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://stockx.com/").build();
        client.newCall(request).execute();
    }
    
    public void fetchState() throws IOException{

        String endpoint = "https://stockx.com/login";

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(endpoint)
                .addHeader("Host", "stockx.com")
                .addHeader("upgrade-insecure-requests", "1")
                .addHeader("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36")
                .addHeader("sec-fetch-mode", "navigate")
                .addHeader("sec-fetch-user", "?1")
                .addHeader("accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9")
                .addHeader("sec-fetch-site", "none")
                .addHeader("accept-language", "pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7")
                .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        if (response.code()==200) {
            String referrer = response.toString();
            String state = referrer.split("state=")[1].split("&")[0];
            String clientID = referrer.split("client_id=")[1].split("&")[0];
            System.out.println(state);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `referrer` String look like when you get it back?

Comment: `Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=https://accounts.stockx.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=OVxrt4VJqTx7LIUKd661W0DuVMpcFByD&connection=production&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fstockx.com%2Fcallback%3Fpath%3D%2F&state=%7B%7D&stockx-session-id=&stockx-default-tab=login&stockx-is-gdpr=&stockx-language=en&stockx-currency=USD&stockx-url=https%3A%2F%2Fstockx.com&audience=gateway.stockx.com&stockx-user-agent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F89.0.4389.128%20Safari%2F537.36}`

Answer (score 0):

Can you post what value you got for referrer?

```
but my code always gives: %7B%7D
```

You may have to use [URLDecoder.decode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

Comment: `Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=https://accounts.stockx.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=OVxrt4VJqTx7LIUKd661W0DuVMpcFByD&connection=production&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fstockx.com%2Fcallback%3Fpath%3D%2F&state=%7B%7D&stockx-session-id=&stockx-default-tab=login&stockx-is-gdpr=&stockx-language=en&stockx-currency=USD&stockx-url=https%3A%2F%2Fstockx.com&audience=gateway.stockx.com&stockx-user-agent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F89.0.4389.128%20Safari%2F537.36}`